# Iterate over tr's in tbody with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

**Set-up**

I have a table in my WordPress backend with several rows. Each row contains a link that I want to open using Selenium.

That is, I want to loop over each `<tr>` in `<tbody>`.

`browser` is defined as,

`browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='mypath')`

The `<tbody>` has the usual form,

```
 <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    ...
    <tr>...</tr>
 </tbody>
```

---

**Code so far**

- Single `<tr>`

After navigating to the correct page,

```
tbody = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.widefat > tbody:nth-child(2)')

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Dutch: Add translation"]').click()
```

The `<tbody>` element is correctly selected, and the right link of the first `<tr>` is correctly opened.

- Loop over `<tr>`'s

I don't know how to successfully loop this over all the `<tr>`'s in the `<tbody>`.

I have tried the following,

```
tbody = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.widefat > tbody:nth-child(2)')

for row in tbody.find_element_by_xpath('./tr'):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Dutch: Add translation"]').click()
```

but this gives `TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable`.

Clearly, `tbody.find_element_by_xpath('./tr')` is not the correct way of selecting all `<tr>`'s.

**How do I select all `<tr>`'s correctly?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`for row in tbody.find_element_by_xpath('./tr')` intend to iterate through *single* WebElement while you need to iterate through *the list* of elements:

```
for row in tbody.find_elements_by_xpath('./tr')
```

Comment: Uff, that was obvious... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use (notice the `s`):

```
tbody.find_elements_by_xpath('./tr')
```

Instead of:

```
tbody.find_element_by_xpath('./tr')
```

which only returns the first match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_element_by_xpath` method as specified earlier but also `find_elements_by_tag_name` which I prefer to use.

```
tbody_rows = tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
for tbody_row in tbody_rows:
    #do your stuff here with each row in turn
```